# Hyperledger Fabric Chaincode Installation Failed - no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am doing the Hyperledger Fabric Tutorial: [Running a Fabric Application](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html) and I am at the **Set up the Blockchain network section**. I am using M1 MacBook Pro, and I need to deploy the chaincode using

`./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-javascript/ -ccl javascript`

Unfortunately it failed with the result

`Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker image build failed: docker build failed: Failed to pull hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv:2.3: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries`

`Chaincode installation on peer0.org1 has failed`

`Deploying chaincode failed`

I am very new to docker and hyperledger fabric, so I am unsure what I should do regarding docker failing to pull hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv:2.3, and the problem with linux/arm64/v8 not in the manifest list entries.

Note that I am using M1 MacBook Pro and this is my current machine and the operating system running on it:

`Darwin Edmunds-MBP 20.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Mon Aug 30 06:12:20 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.6~3/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 x86_64`

Answer (score 8):

You can pull the image with linux platform first, before run command from the tutorial.

```
docker pull --platform linux/x86_64 hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv:2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I tried to resolve the issue for days. Here is what you need to do:

Before you run:

```
./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-javascript/ -ccl javascript
```

Run this command:

```
docker pull --platform linux/x86_64 hyperledger/fabric-javaenv:2.4
```

After that run the chaincode initialization command again.